# Why do numerics get rounded when using apply+paste when a dataframe has a text column?

Tags: r

When apply+paste is called on a dataframe with one or more text columns, decimal numbers become rounded to the number of digits given by the current display settings (via options(digits)).

The normal behaviour for a dataframe without a text column is like so:

```
data.frame(col1 = c(1.23456,2.23456,3.23456), col2 = c(2,3,4)) %>% apply(1, paste)

     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] "1.23456" "2.23456" "3.23456"
[2,] "2"       "3"       "4"
```

However, when a text column is introduced, the values in col1 become rounded down:

```
data.frame(col1 = c(1.23456,2.23456,3.23456), col2 = c('b','a','d')) %>% apply(1, paste)

     [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
[1,] "1.2" "2.2" "3.2"
[2,] "b"   "a"   "d"
```

Is there a way to avoid this? The output that I would like to see is:

```
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] "1.23456" "2.23456" "3.23456"
[2,] "b"   "a"   "d"
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I get the same output as shown in your expected output when using `data.frame(col1 = c(1.23456,2.23456,3.23456), col2 = c('b','a','d')) %>% apply(1, paste)`

Answer (score 0):

You can inhibit the conversion of numeric objects before passing the data frame to apply:

```
library(dplyr)

options(digits = 2)

data.frame(col1 = c(1.23456,2.23456,3.23456), col2 = c('b','a','d')) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), I)) %>%
  apply(1, paste)

     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] "1.23456" "2.23456" "3.23456"
[2,] "b"       "a"       "d"
```

Or by formatting the data frame beforehand:

```
data.frame(col1 = c(1.23456,2.23456,3.23456), col2 = c('b','a','d')) %>% 
  format(digits = max(nchar(.$col1))) %>%
  apply(1, paste)
```